# How to Enable the Console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working with Java on Eclipse for Windows.
When I click the run button I can't see the console anywhere. How can I enable the console in eclipse

Comment: is the program waiting for input?

Comment: No. There must be a writing space for my input after click run button but it doesn't come

Comment: The "writing space" is the console where output is routed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Sibbo said, you need to enter something into the console in order for the program to work. To get the console up in eclipse, go to **Window**, **Show View**, **Console** (as shown in the picture below.) Then run your program, enter content in the console and await for the same thing to be printed back

[image: Open up the Console]

Comment: ohh. Thank you bro. Sorry I can't vote your answer because of my rep

Answer (score 3):

The program is waiting for input. Click on the console on the bottom of the window and enter something. Then press enter. The same text will appear.

Comment: There is not a console for my input

Comment: Or via menus: Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Console

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have closed Console? Click "Reset perspective". Console should show up.
Type line into it and hit Enter.

Comment: Where is the reset perspective. And I have just installed eclipse

Comment: Window -> Reset Perspective.